# Formatting into columns with element number and element of list

Tags: python, list, formatting, multiple-columns

Hi I want to make a function which will take a list and return a print out which shows the element number and the corresponding element in two columns.

Here is my stab at it:

```
printList(aList):
    """ Prints the current list.
    """
    print ('%3d %5.2f' % (i, aList[i]))
```

I get an error saying global i is not defined but I'm not sure how to define it.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Note that `#` is more effective for single-line comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well the `i` is really not defined. you are missing the loop

```
for i in range(len(aList)):
    ...
```

Comment: just add a `print ...` before the loop